# Require return type of function template to be specialization of a template

Tags: c++, gcc

I've poked around on stackoverflow for a while, but either I don't understand templates enough to find a solution, or it simply hasn't been answered before.

In this example:

```
template <typename T> T f();
```

Is it possible to make the function require type T to be a specialization of the `std::basic_string` template?

I could have the template defined with T as the type of the `std::basic_string` as so (using `std::basic_string<T>` internally, of course):

```
template <typename T> std::basic_string<T> f();
```

But then I would not be able to pass `std::string` or `std::wstring` to the function (expecting the return type to be `std::string` and `std::wstring`, respectively), which is the real aim here (to be able to pass any type which derives from the `std::basic_string` template).

Comment: @plash please indicate whether you mean "derived from" or "specialization of". In your original post you said "derived from". Potatoswatter changed the title of it to say "specialization of" but left the main text alone. What's your actual intention? Please fix that in your question. Your last paragraph reads to me like "I would not be able to pass std::string because then it looks like `std::basic_string<std::string>`.". It doesn't necessarily follow from your main text what precisely you mean.

Comment: If I understood the terminology, I would have used 'specialization'. Can you even derive from templated classes?

Comment: @plash thanks, now it's clear. Well collegially I would interpret "derive from basic_string" as saying the class derives from `basic_string<T>`. So in some sense, it's ambiguous :)

Comment: @plash: yes you can. In fact, you can derive both from a class template (i.e. something without template arguments filled in, such as `basic_istream<TElem>` ) as well as a class that is a template instantiation (i.e. a concrete class such as `basic_istream<char>`).

Comment: However, `struct A : basic_istream { };` surely is not valid (you have to fill in arguments like `basic_istream<T>`). In that way, you cannt derive from class templates. As you see, now you, @Konrad and me all have three different interpretations of "deriving from class template", which proves how ambiguous this is :)

Comment: @Konrad: Then my original use of 'derive' was certainly wrong :)

Comment: @Johannes: I beg to differ. “Of course” when you derive from a class template what you get is once again a *template*, i.e. it needs to specify template arguments. You can’t magically get from a template to a class without instantiating the template. In that sense, I don’t see an ambiguity: either you derive from a template or from a class.

Comment: @Konrad as "derive from a class template" is not a defined procedure by C++, it makes no sense to argue about it. You apparently interpret it as deriving from a dependent class template specialization, and i interpret it as "deriving from a template" (well, I can't think of another term to describe `: basic_string`). If you interpret it like I suspect, there is no "either or": Because a dependent class template specialization does name a class (dependent class), you in fact derive from a class instead of a template (Well, it's impossible to argue about it with different definitions in mind).

Comment: @Konrad when you derive from a dependent class template specialization you don't necessarily get a template. Consider this case: `template<typename T> class A { class B : basic_string<T> { }; };`. Now `A<>::B` is a non-template nested class of a class template.

Comment: @Johannes: I just noticed that you’re right. What I was talking about is not, in fact a class template. It’s of course what you said, a dependent class template instantiation (it’s “instantiation”, not “specialization”, right?).

Comment: @Konrad it's a specialization. It's not necessarily an instantiation for templates other than `basic_string`. Instantiations are special kind of specializations. The relation is: An instantiation is a generated specialization of a template. An explicit specialization is a user-provided specialization of a template. If you just talk about `foo<T>`, you correctly have to say "specialization" because you can't know whether it's explicitly specialized or not. If it isn't, it will require an instantiation to generate it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Partial specialization allows you to test whether a type is a specialization of a particular template. SFINAE is a trick that can "switch off" a function template declaration. The solution combines these techniques.

```
template< typename T > // by default,
struct enable_if_basic_string {}; // a type is not a basic_string

template< typename CharT, typename Traits >
struct enable_if_basic_string< basic_string< CharT, Traits > > {
    typedef basic_string< CharT, Traits > type; // same as argument type
};

// enable_if_basic_string<>::type exists only if T specializes basic_string
// if not, compiler ignores function declaration per SFINAE.
template< typename T >
typename enable_if_basic_string< T >::type
F() {
    .....
}
```

If you mean derivation as well as specialization, you might take a look at `std::tr1::is_convertible` and `enable_if` as well.

Comment: +1 - It definitely solves the problem. Unfortunately it also requires you to decorate functions with useless parameters, though thankfully that can be hidden with default arguments.

Comment: @Paul: No, there is no parameter there. I didn't change the template or runtime arguments of his function at all.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Yes, for this application. I was referring to using this idiom when you already have a return type in mind. Sorry I wasn't clearer.

Comment: Which answer is a more correct answer to this question? I'm thinking it's this one, but I won't be using it simply because I won't expect any non basic_string specialized type, and because this one is more complex and I dislike using magic.

Comment: @plash: I don't think there is any reason to artificially limit a template, if it could work equally well for other unrelated types. - @paul: `boost::enable_if` lets you choose the typedeffed `type`, therefore a hidden argument is only needed for constructors, otherwise you can always use `enable_if` on the return type.

Comment: @visitor: True, but then I could just yell at whoever defied the documentation and used a non basic_string specialized type.

Comment: @plash: Has anyone suggested that you just go with the original code in the question? `template <typename T> std::basic_string<T> f();` *does* allow you to pass `std::string` or `std::wstring`; just use the template arguments `char` or `wchar_t` respectively.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Yes it does allow that, but I wanted to avoid doing it.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of requiring that `T` be a specialization of `std::basic_string`, why not just *assume* that `T` is a specialization of `std::basic_string` and let template instantiation fail if it isn't.  Just use the things from `std::basic_string` that you need.

For example,

```
template <typename T>
T get_first_three_chars(const T& str) { return str.substr(0, 3); }
```

Here, we assume that `T` has a member function `substr`; if it doesn't, then instantiation will fail, resulting in a compilation error.

Comment: Mmm. How does this look? http://pastebin.com/xiL8TGSn
I presume I shouldn't be using string pointers, but.. it compiles.
EDIT: Scratch that. This works perfectly for what I needed: http://pastebin.com/kptMXUPL
Anything look wrong with it?

Comment: Other than it being pointers rather than references that is.. For some reason I can't edit that comment anymore, so here's what I'm left with: http://pastebin.com/6yQdTWYV

Comment: @plash: You can edit comments only for a grace period of 5mins.

Comment: @Johannes, @Potatoswatter:  Oops.  Brain compiler fail.  Thank you :-)

Comment: Is this more similar to my suggestion than intended? If you return `T::value_type`, then lack of such a member causes SFINAE, not a compiler error. `T f() { T::value_type x; return T(); }` would illustrate the "just let it work" option.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in vanilla C++. There was a language construct proposed for C++0x that would allow for this, unfortunately it was dropped.

You can do this to a certain degree with the Boost Concept Check Library, however: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/concept_check/concept_check.htm

Comment: I can't comment on James McNellis' post because of some inane reputation requirement so I'll say this here: I'm new to Stack Overflow, and one trend I commonly see in answering questions is to not actually answer the question, but instead ignore the problem. Is this normal for Stack Overflow, or did I simply decide to join at the wrong time?

Comment: Dunno. I'm not around here very often.

I know for one that I will never use Boost. Your response does answer my question, but doesn't give me a solution.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you choose not to use boost, or is it limitation from your job?

Edit: Also, in the code you posted as a comment above, consider using references whenever possible and only revert to pointers when specific functionality is required.

Comment: I don't want to bloat my library. I'm not working for anyone.
Also, I now know that std::basic_string is immutable, so for when strings will be passed without being modified, I'll pass them as references.

Comment: @plash: `std::basic_string` is mutable.

Comment: @Paul: According to the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), the rep required to leave comments is at 50. While I write this, you have 61.

Comment: @sbi: Yes it is. However, when I posted I did not meet the requirements.

Comment: @Paul: Well, congratulations for taking that hurdle! `:)`

Comment: @sbi: So if I pass one as non-reference it won't be copied?

Comment: @Paul: It *is* possible in vanilla C++ (no need for concepts). Have a look at Potatoswatter’s answer. Variations of his answer are routinely used in several libraries.

Comment: @plash: Um, I'm confused. I thought _"immutable string"_ means that its content cannot be altered? What does this have to do with copying?

Comment: @sbi: I think *I'm* the confused one. In languages that I've used that have immutable strings, copies of the object are _always_ made when you pass them by-value. Well, whatever, passing them by-ref is the right way to do it regardless of immutability.

Comment: @plash: In C++, immutability has nothing to do with pass-per-value vs. pass-per-reference. `std::basic_string` is mutable, you can change a string's content. Independently of that, you are free to pass function parameters any way you like, although [there are established patterns for passing objects to functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139224/how-to-pass-objects-to-functions-in-c/2139254#2139254).

Comment: @Paul: To answer the question in your first comment: a lot of times the OP may not entirely understand that there are other, usually better, and more commonly used alternatives.  I might have put my non-direct-answer answer in a comment, but it wouldn't fit in a comment and it's hard to format even small code examples in a comment. Potatoswatter gives a good solution explaining how the OP can do what he asks for, but in most cases, I don't think that's what he really needs: usually, just assuming you have a type that meets certain criteria works just fine. [Also, welcome to Stack Overflow :-)]