# How do I require template parameters to be specializations of a specific template class?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, template-specialization, c++-concepts

I would like to define a template class `MyClass` where the template parameters must be specializations of specific template classes. In this example, I would like `MyClass` to be a template class that accepts for its first template parameter a specialization of `A` and for its second template parameter a specialization of `B`. I may then instantiate this class as follows:

```
MyClass<A<int, int>, B<double, int>>;
```

Now, you might say, "just take the arguments of `A` and `B` as the template parameters of `MyClass`". Unfortunately, in my situation, `A` and `B` are both variadic templates, and so it won't be possible in the parameter list for `MyClass` to find the end of the template arguments for `A` and the beginning of the template arguments for `B`.

Examples of `A` and `B` follow:

```
template <typename... Args>
class A{
public:
    A(){}
};
```

```
template <typename... Args>
class B{
public:
    B(){}
};
```

I have found [older answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732802/require-return-type-of-function-template-to-be-specialization-of-a-template) that provide solutions like using SFINAE. My understanding is that, unfortunately, SFINAE has drawbacks like disabling type deduction; I tend to avoid it. My question is this: **are there newer language features that allow me to get the behavior I want without SFINAE?**

To give you a bit better idea of what I am imagining for `MyClass`, I provide this *bad* example below:

```
template <template<typename... Args> class A, typename... Args1, template<typename... Args> class B, typename... Args2>
class MyClass { // use A<Args1...> and B<Args2...> in here
public:
    MyClass() {}
}; // fails because template parameter pack Args1 is not at the end of the parameter list
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to SFINAE are [**C++20 constraints and concepts**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints). In your case - regardless of SFINAE or concepts - the [key problem will be the template parameter packs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68186697/9938686), as [the standard dictates](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param#14)

> A template parameter pack of a function template shall not be followed by another template parameter unless that template parameter can be deduced from the parameter-type-list ([dcl.fct]) of the function template or has a default argument ([temp.deduct]). A template parameter of a deduction guide template ([temp.deduct.guide]) that does not have a default argument shall be deducible from the parameter-type-list of the deduction guide template.

This means that you can't have something like

```
template <template<typename...> class A, typename... Args1, template<typename...> class B, typename... Args2>
class MyClass {
  public:
    MyClass() {}
};
```

directly.

- One possible solution is to **not have a template template class at all** and make sure **implicitly** (e.g. by a function call to a properly overloaded function) that the template arguments are correct. You could actually formalise @cigien's approach with concepts and further remove the requirement of default-constructability by using [`std::declval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval):

  Introduce two functions that can only be called by objects of type `A` and `B` respectively:

  ```
  template <typename... Args>
  void a(A<Args...>) {}

  template <typename... Args>
  void b(B<Args...>) {}
  ```

  Define two concepts which require that an overload of the corresponding function exists that can be called with a value of the corresponding type by using [`std::declval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) instead of the default-constructor:

  ```
  template <typename T>
  concept is_A = requires { a(std::declval<T>()); };

  template <typename T>
  concept is_B = requires { b(std::declval<T>()); };
  ```

  Finally enforce the corresponding concepts on your template parameters as follows:

  ```
  template <is_A A, is_B B>
  class MyClass {
  public:
    MyClass() {}
  };
  ```

  With this approach the class can be default-constructed with

  ```
  MyClass<A<int,int>, B<double,int>> my_class{};
  ```

  Contrary to @cigien's version this **does not require `A` and `B` to be default-constructible**!

  [Try it here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/NVR80VtYgDqDGq2n)

---

Depending on your planned usage you could also use the **template argument deduction** when the constructor is called but be aware that then the class itself will not distinguish between different variadic template arguments (meaning `std::is_same` will actually return true for two different parameter packs), only the constructor will. Furthermore the class won't be default constructable anymore and you would have to call it with

```
MyClass my_class{A<int,int>{}, B<int,double>{}};
```

- One way would be to not template the class at all and template the constructor with two template parameter packs

  ```
  class MyClass {
    public:
      template <typename... Args1, typename... Args2>
      MyClass(A<Args1...>, B<Args2...>) {}
  };
  ```

  [Try it here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nzgfKLndDbbtMcTj)
- You could make this more flexible by introducing the concepts

  ```
  template <template<typename...> class T, typename... Ts>
  concept is_A = std::is_same_v<A<Ts...>,T<Ts...>>;

  template <template<typename...> class T, typename... Ts>
  concept is_B = std::is_same_v<B<Ts...>,T<Ts...>>;
  ```

  (or alternatively with `std::is_base_of` instead), templating the class without specifying the variadic template parameters and then making the constructor templated as well with two template parameter packs that can be deducted from the input arguments

  ```
  template <template<typename...> class C1, template<typename...> class C2>
  requires is_A<C1> && is_B<C2>
  class MyClass {
    public:
      template <typename... Args1, typename... Args2>
      requires is_A<C1,Args1...> && is_B<C2,Args2...>
      MyClass(C1<Args1...>, C2<Args2...>) {}
  };
  ```

  and add a requires clause to the class and/or constructor.

  [Try it here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mxuT2oI1q9ypNtjL).

The given constraints could of course also be enforced with SFINAE [`std::enable_if_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) instead of concepts. For an example of this see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67705635/9938686).

Comment: I hope that one day the cppreference page on constraints and concepts can be fleshed out.

Comment: @mana I am sure it will be soon. Wide-spread use of concepts is around the corner. I am really looking forward to that. Codes using them is much more expressive than `std::enable_if`. Do you really need to construct it with `MyClass<A<int, int>, B<double, int>>;`  or would `MyClass my_class {A<int, int>{}, B<double, int>{}};` also be an option?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible by specializing class templates, but you can work around this by using function template argument deduction, which can distinguish between multiple parameter packs

```
template <typename... Args1, typename... Args2>
void f(A<Args1...>, B<Args2...>) {}
```

This function will be matched when passed instantiations of `A` and `B`, which we use as the true case.

For the false case, we can just match anything and delete it

```
template <typename... Ts>
void f(Ts...) = delete;
```

Now, you can have `MyClass` take 2 type parameters, and call `f`, say in the constructor, to make sure the parameters are instantiations of `A` and `B`.

```
template<typename T, typename U>
class MyClass { 
public:
    MyClass() 
    {
        f(T{}, U{});  // hard error if not called with specializations of A and B
    }
};
```

This will essentially assert that the types satisfy the constraints you want, but you can further extract the arguments of `A` and `B` if you want to use them as well.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/r6b94fxEe).